# Doubt in one disadvantage of doing work in constructors

Tags: c++

I was reading Google C++ Style Guide, and got confused in the [Doing Work in Constructors](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Doing_Work_in_Constructors#Doing_Work_in_Constructors) part. One of the cons of doing heavy work in constructor is:

> If the work calls virtual functions,
>   these calls will not get dispatched to
>   the subclass implementations. Future
>   modification to your class can quietly
>   introduce this problem even if your
>   class is not currently subclassed,
>   causing much confusion.

I didn't understand what it means. Could someone provide an explanation and why this may be considered a disadvantage?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I dislike the google c++ style guide. Calling virtual methods from constructors and destructors should be avoided per se as a rule of thumb --where avoid is only do it if you have a good reason and can defend it in a code review. On the other hand, the recommendation to use a two step initialization is (arguably) plain wrong, and many other style guides recommend against two step initialization...

Comment: Bear in mind that Google's style guide is for not C++, despite the page title. They forbid exceptions, giving a bastardised language in which many C++ idioms either can't be used, or are stripped of their usefulness. This is the reason that they require two-stage initialisation, and all the error-prone headaches that entails; there's no way to indicate failure from a constructor. Unless you have a specific reason to follow Google's style, ignore it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm blatantly ripping off some example code from the Wikipedia [Virtual function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) page:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Animal {
    public:
        virtual void eat() const { 
            std::cout << "I eat like a generic Animal." << std::endl; 
        }
        virtual ~Animal() { 
        }
};

class Wolf : public Animal {
    public:
        void eat() const { 
            std::cout << "I eat like a wolf!" << std::endl; 
        }
};

class Fish : public Animal {
    public:
        void eat() const { 
            std::cout << "I eat like a fish!" << std::endl; 
        }
};
```

If you call `eat()` inside the `Animal` constructor, it will call the `Animal` `eat()` function every time.  Even when you create a `Wolf` or a `Fish` object, since the `Animal` constructor will complete before the subclass object is initialized, the overriding `eat` functions won't exist yet.

This is a disadvantage because it can cause confusion between what's expected and what actually happens.  If I override `eat` then create an object of my subclass, I expect my overridden function to be called, even from an `Animal` reference.  I expect it because that's what happens when the call is made explicitly by code outside the constructor.  The behavior is different inside the constructor, causing me to scratch my head in bewilderment.

Answer (score 4):

When an object is being constructed, the constructors for base classes are called first. Since the derived class hasn't been initialized yet, any calls to virtual methods during the base class constructor won't have a derived class object to work on.

Answer (score 2):

When an instance of a subclass is created, first is called the constructor of the base class, then the constructor of the subclass.

If the base class constructor calls a virtual method then the method of the base class will be called instead of the subclass, although the instance is that of a subclass. This could be a problem.

A lot more information here: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/nevercall.html

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit from the class, the methods that you override/implement will not be called in this case. So, if Employee calls work() in the constructor, then later on you come up with Hourly::work() and SalariedEmployee::work(), those won't get called. Even though they have different implementations, they'll still be treated as Employee, not their special implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor's job is simply to initialize your object's initial state.  If you start performing tasks that rely on actions taken in virtual functions, you can get some unexpected results when subclasses start implementing these functions.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that virtual function calls aren't virtual is well-defined but very surprising, so compilers usually emit warnings.